# Dimension of Specht Module of $S_n$ over a Finite Field of characteristic $p > n$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

We know that over $\mathbb{C}$ the Specht modules give a complete set of irreducible representations of $S_n$. I want to calculate the dimensions of irreducible representations of $S_6$ over a finite field of characteristic $p > 6$.

Will it match with the dimension of the Specht modules over $\mathbb{C}$?

Even a reference would do.

Comment: Yes, it will match. This is general representation theory for $p\nmid |G|$, nothing to do with symmetric groups. Being a symmetric group is only needed to know that every field is a splitting field for $S_n$,. i.e., there are the correct number of irreducible representations. (Think the cyclic group of order $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks for the answer. Do you have a reference for this ?

Comment: @alpha123: The character theory book by Isaacs might be helpful, Chapter 9 and Chapter 15. See for example Theorem 15.13.